Python's Selenium4 ChromeDriver crash when in non headless mode (works in headless mode): selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException
I have a Python's Selenium4 with ChromeDriver script that refuse to start when in non headless mode:
I have another scripts with the same imports, and the other ones don't crash.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/selenium_scraper.py", line 92, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(                         
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55b34ba06f83 <unknown>
#1 0x55b34b6bfcf7 <unknown>
#2 0x55b34b6f760e <unknown>
#3 0x55b34b6f426e <unknown>
#4 0x55b34b74480c <unknown>
#5 0x55b34b738e53 <unknown>
#5 0x55b34b700dd4 <unknown>
#7 0x55b34b7021de <unknown>
#8 0x55b34b9cb531 <unknown>
#9 0x55b34b9cf455 <unknown>
#10 0x55b34b9b7f55 <unknown>
#11 0x55b34b9d00ef <unknown>
#12 0x55b34b99b99f <unknown>
#13 0x55b34b9f4008 <unknown>
#14 0x55b34b9f41d7 <unknown>
#15 0x55b34ba06124 <unknown>
#16 0x7f961961fea7 start_thread

Line 93 is driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
Only significative difference with others scrapers with the same code base: I delete the Chromium profile before running, but not for this one.
Searched a lot on the web, found https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6049 I'm not alone. This is a very obscure bug.

After scratching my head for many hours, figured it out:
I needed to purge my --user-data-dir=/path/to/profil_X, so:
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium/profil_X/*

Now the script is running seamlessly.
This is due to different uses of the profile, like switching from GUI to headless and vice versa

I'm glad you found the answer to your question. Please make sure that you come back soon and mark this as the answer so the question doesn't get left unanswered. Thanks!
